# Just what is making my Linux box so unresponsive?

Tags: linux

(I'm using Ethereum as an example, but my real question is how I can figure out what is going on, on a box that behaves in this way.)

I'm running Ethereum on an (admittedly slow) PC, on Linux with KDE. After a few hours, when I touch the mouse, the mouse pointer doesn't move at all first. It takes some time before the mouse pointer moves, but then only in big jumps. Then, logging into the box sometimes takes more than 10min of patience. Just what exactly is going on here, and how can I change this?

To my surprise, `nice` and `ionice` change little.

Here's what I know:

- `free` shows a bunch of free RAM, and little use of swap space
- `top` shows good utilization, but that shouldn't really matter if I `nice` the process, right?
- `iotop` shows "jumpy" I/O utiliztion, but nowhere sustained, and `ionice` should de-prioritize anyway, right?
- there's almost no graphics activity
- there's very moderate network traffic

What am I missing, and what tools can I use to understand this?

Comment: Use preemtible kernel, but when it's not enough use [cgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups) for limiting ethereum process.

Comment: If this does something, wouldn't that mean that Ethereum spends a lot of time in the kernel? (Doing what?) Is there a way to figure out whether this is true?